# setTimeout Not Returning value

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

I am using `setTimeout` for getting new data at interval of 30 seconds, but it's not working, don't know where it's messed up. Here is my code:

```
(function pollmsg() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var demon = $('.msgnotimore').val();
        var a = $('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'modules/notifications/beast.php?nid=' + demon + '&id=' + a,
            success: function (data) {
                $('.notiloadmsg').append($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
                alert(data);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: pollmsg
        });
    }, 30000);
})();
```

When I try to alert `demon`, it alerts `demon` after 30 sec, but the data is not alerted.

Comment: If you indent your code properly, we have a chance to understand it... thank you.

Comment: Does the URL return valid JSON? If not, the success callback is not executed.

Comment: In chrome use the Javascript console to see if any underlying errors occur.

Comment: sorry for the format and i m tryin to get html from other file , i am using setTimeout for the first time and not able to get data

Comment: So the URL returns HTML? Then why are you telling jQuery to expect JSON (`dataType: "json"`)?

Comment: nope no error in chrome just i checked it

Comment: then what to use for that i m using it for the first time can you please help me out in this

Comment: Use `"html"` instead... whenever you use a function you're not familiar with very much, check its documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataType: "json"` should not be used when fetching `HTML` instead use `"html"`

Comment: thank you friend for helping me out though it was a basic question, but still , u helped out and thank you @Felix Kling also for helping out , bithaway can i ask is this the right method for polling ?

Comment: @SakshiSharma I think it is better practice to `setTimeout` from within the callback to protect against very slow internet connections.